React Native Reanimated: Swipeable Tabs Work, but Clicking on Tab Titles Only Works Once
I'm building a swipeable tab system in my React Native app using react-native-reanimated and react-native-gesture-handler. The user can swipe between tabs or click on the tab titles to navigate. Swiping between tabs works perfectly, but clicking on a tab title only works once. After clicking a title, I must swipe again before being able to click another title.
Below is the current implementation:
Code for Home.tsx (Main Component):
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Dimensions, View } from "react-native";
import {
  PanGestureHandler,
  PanGestureHandlerGestureEvent,
} from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import Animated, {
  useSharedValue,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  withSpring,
} from "react-native-reanimated";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";

import { FeedProvider, useAuth } from "replyke-rn";
import { Feed } from "../../components/home/Feed";
import { cn } from "../../utils/cn";
import { TabsSlidingTitles } from "../../components/home/TabsSlidingTitles";
import { FEEDS, feedTitles } from "../../components/home/feeds";

const { width: SCREEN_WIDTH } = Dimensions.get("window");

type ScreenCount = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4;
const containerWidth: Record<ScreenCount, string> = {
  1: "w-full",
  2: "w-[200%]",
  3: "w-[300%]",
  4: "w-[400%]",
};

const Home = () => {
  const { user } = useAuth();

  // Keep your original React state for the active feed:
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState<number>(1); // start on the second feed

  // Keep a shared value in sync with that state:
  const currentIndexSV = useSharedValue(currentIndex);

  // On each render if currentIndex changes, update currentIndexSV
  useEffect(() => {
    currentIndexSV.value = currentIndex;
  }, [currentIndex]);

  // TranslateX starts at -SCREEN_WIDTH for feed #1
  const translateX = useSharedValue(-SCREEN_WIDTH);

  const screenCount = feedTitles.length;

  // -- GESTURE HANDLER (Swipe) --

  const handleGestureEvent = (event: PanGestureHandlerGestureEvent) => {
    const minTranslateX = -(screenCount - 1) * SCREEN_WIDTH;
    const maxTranslateX = 0;

    translateX.value = Math.min(
      maxTranslateX,
      Math.max(
        minTranslateX,
        event.nativeEvent.translationX + currentIndexSV.value * -SCREEN_WIDTH
      )
    );
  };

  const handleGestureEnd = () => {
    const threshold = SCREEN_WIDTH / 5;

    const newIndex =
      translateX.value > -(currentIndexSV.value * SCREEN_WIDTH) + threshold
        ? Math.max(currentIndexSV.value - 1, 0)
        : translateX.value < -(currentIndexSV.value * SCREEN_WIDTH) - threshold
        ? Math.min(currentIndexSV.value + 1, screenCount - 1)
        : currentIndexSV.value;

    // Update both React state and shared value
    setCurrentIndex(newIndex);
    currentIndexSV.value = newIndex;

    translateX.value = withSpring(newIndex * -SCREEN_WIDTH, {
      damping: 20,
      stiffness: 150,
      mass: 1,
      overshootClamping: true,
    });
  };

  // -- TITLE TAPS (Click) --
  const handleTitlePress = (index: number) => {
    // If you truly want to disable re-tapping the same feed, check against currentIndexSV:
    // if (index === currentIndexSV.value) return;

    setCurrentIndex(index);
    // Immediately update the shared value so the gesture code sees the correct feed
    currentIndexSV.value = index;

    translateX.value = withSpring(index * -SCREEN_WIDTH, {
      damping: 20,
      stiffness: 150,
      mass: 1,
      overshootClamping: true,
    });
  };

  // Animated style that just uses translateX
  const animatedFeedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
    transform: [{ translateX: translateX.value }],
  }));

  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar style="light" backgroundColor="black" />
      <SafeAreaView className="relative flex-1">
        <View className="relative z-20">
          <TabsSlidingTitles
            titles={feedTitles}
            translateX={translateX}
            screenWidth={SCREEN_WIDTH}
            onTitlePress={handleTitlePress}
          />
        </View>

        <PanGestureHandler
          onGestureEvent={handleGestureEvent}
          onEnded={handleGestureEnd}
          activeOffsetX={[-20, 20]}
        >
          <Animated.View
            style={animatedFeedStyle}
            className={cn(
              "flex-1 flex-row",
              containerWidth[screenCount as ScreenCount]
            )}
          >
            {FEEDS(user).map((feed, index) => (
              <View key={index} className="flex-1 w-screen">
                {feed.component || (
                  <FeedProvider {...feed.providerProps}>
                    <Feed />
                  </FeedProvider>
                )}
              </View>
            ))}
          </Animated.View>
        </PanGestureHandler>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;

Code for TabsSlidingTitles:
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from "react-native";
import Animated, {
  useAnimatedStyle,
  interpolate,
  SharedValue,
} from "react-native-reanimated";

interface TabsSlidingTitlesProps {
  titles: string[];
  translateX: SharedValue<number>;
  screenWidth: number;
  onTitlePress: (index: number) => void; // Add this prop
}

export const TabsSlidingTitles: React.FC<TabsSlidingTitlesProps> = ({
  titles,
  translateX,
  screenWidth,
  onTitlePress,
}) => {
  // Calculate the total width of the titles including gaps
  const titleWidth = screenWidth / 4; // Adjust this to control individual title width
  const gap = 16; // Gap between titles

  const animatedTitlesStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
    transform: [
      {
        translateX: interpolate(
          translateX.value,
          titles.map((_, index) => -index * screenWidth),
          titles.map(
            (_, index) =>
              index * (titleWidth + gap) * -1 +
              (screenWidth - titleWidth - gap) / 2
          )
        ),
      },
    ],
  }));

  return (
    <View className="absolute top-0 left-0 right-0">
      <View className="relative h-16 justify-center">
        {/* Static underline */}
        <View
          className="absolute bottom-0 left-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 h-1 w-24 rounded-md bg-white/50 z-30"
          style={{
            shadowColor: "#00000099",
            shadowRadius: 2,
            shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 },
            elevation: 4,
          }}
        />

        {/* Animated row of titles */}
        <Animated.View
          style={animatedTitlesStyle}
          className="absolute flex-row items-center left-0"
        >
          {titles.map((title, index) => (
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback
              key={index}
              onPress={() => onTitlePress(index)} // Handle press event
            >
              <Text
                className="text-lg font-bold text-center"
                style={{
                  width: titleWidth,
                  marginHorizontal: gap / 2,
                  color: "white",
                  textShadowColor: "#00000099",
                  textShadowRadius: 2,
                  textShadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 },
                }}
              >
                {title}
              </Text>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          ))}
        </Animated.View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};


What Happens

Swiping between tabs works as expected.
Clicking on tab titles only works once. After clicking a title, I need to swipe to a new tab before clicking on another title works again.


What I’ve Tried

Syncing state: I ensured that currentIndexSV updates in a useEffect whenever currentIndex changes.
Avoid redundant clicks: Added a check to skip handleTitlePress if the tapped index is the current index.


Desired Behavior

Clicking on a tab title should reliably navigate to the corresponding tab.
Both swiping and clicking should work without requiring one to "reset" the other.


What am I missing, or how can I fix this issue?
